# Unable to integrate sqlite3 with ruby and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Disclaimer: I checked the FAQs. I have tried Google, Reddit and YouTube and am posting here after exhausting all available options.

I'm using guides.rubyonrails.org to learn. However, SQLite3 has not downloaded on my system, despite following the instructions on the website.

So I typed '`gem install sqlite3`' in the command line and it has thrown multiple errors related to mingw32, mingw64 and msys. The commonality of the errors being they are invalid or corrupted databases (PGP signatures).

The final error stated for installing sqlite3 was "*failed to build gem native extension*" followed by the directory and a suggestion to install it from the net.

I have installed it from sqlite.org and integrated it with the regular command prompt. Here it says "*connected to a transient in memory database*".

It is not integrated in the command prompt with ruby. Here it says "*the term 'sqlite3' is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.*"

I'm using a laptop using **Windows 10** and have **rails 6.0.3.2** and **ruby 2.7.1** installed.

I tried progressing irrespective and my input was '`rails server`' on the regular command prompt.

The following lines showed up -

```
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (~> 1.4) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.

Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems.
```

Please advise how to progress or if there's anything I'm missing. Should I persist and try and fix the error in the ruby command prompt or move forward with the regular command prompt? None of them are working for me to progress my learning. Let me know if you require more information.

Thanks for your time and help.

**EDIT**: Here is the image for when I run gem install sqlite3.
[image]

**2nd EDIT**: Here is what I get when I run '`rails new blog`' and '`bundle install`' thereafter.
[image]

**3rd EDIT**: Here is the mkmf file where the problem exists as per command prompt.
[image]

**4th EDIT**: I followed the instructions on guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. I ran 'bundle install' only when it asked me to after I ran 'rails new blog' in the command line.

Similar error regarding mingw32, mingw64 and msys from the first image came up after I ran bundle install in blog. However, this time it stated `Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

Comment: Have you added  gem 'sqlite3' to your gem file and run "bundle install" ?

Comment: please show full backtraces when you run ```gem install sqlite3```

Comment: @Spikie Added image. Please let me know if you require anything else.

Comment: @dbugger I am new to this. How should I do that? I ran 'bundle install' and it said "Could not locate Gemfile".

Comment: How'd you set up this project?  Did you run bundle install from the app directory?

Comment: @dbugger I followed the instructions on https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. I ran 'bundle install' only when it asked me to after I ran 'rails new blog' in the command line.

Comment: do you have a gem file?  Where is it?  Where did you run the bundle install command? Please add this info to the question and also the contents of your gem file.

Comment: @dbugger I have added a second image for your questions. Please let me know if you require any other information.

Comment: Actually need to go into the blog directory and run commands, unless Boobay is the blog directory.

Comment: @dbugger Did so in the blog directory. Similar error regarding mingw32, mingw64 and msys from the first image came up. However, this time it stated `Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

Comment: Include all information into question as text.

Comment: @D.SM I have done that, please let me know if anything else is required.